# Creating a custom view with PKHUD in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to create a custom view using PKHUD so that when API calls fail I can display a message to our users along with a button to call for help.

Here is my class file:

```
import UIKit
import PKHUD

class PKHUDHelpDeskView: PKHUDWideBaseView {

    private func callNumber(phoneNumber:String) {
        if let phoneCallURL = URL(string: "tel:\(phoneNumber)") {
            let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
            if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    application.open(phoneCallURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func helpDeskNumberButton(_ sender: Any) {
        callNumber(phoneNumber: "8005551234")
    }
}
```

Here is how I am calling it:

```
PKHUD.sharedHUD.contentView = PKHUDHelpDeskView()
PKHUD.sharedHUD.show()
PKHUD.sharedHUD.hide(afterDelay: 4.0)
```

I have a view set up in storyboard (with the class set to PKHUDHelpDeskView) with the button and the a text field displaying the message. When I run this, the PKHUD displays with no text in it. The class file and the storyboard are properly connected, so what needs to be done to get the text to display in the PKHUD?

Answer (score 2):

I tried doing the same. Instead of adding `UILabel` and `UIButton` using storyboard(I believe you are referring to .xib here), I added them programatically. The following is my final code. Please try it out

```
import PKHUD

class PKHUDHelpDeskView: PKHUDWideBaseView {

    let button: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
    let label: UILabel = UILabel()

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()

        button.setTitle("Call", for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.helpDeskNumberButton(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        label.text = "Call me now"
        label.textColor = UIColor.brown
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

        self.addSubview(label)
        self.addSubview(button)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width/2, height: 30.0)
        self.label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 30.0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 40.0)
    }

    private func callNumber(phoneNumber:String) {
        if let phoneCallURL = URL(string: "tel:\(phoneNumber)") {
            let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
            if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    application.open(phoneCallURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func helpDeskNumberButton(_ sender: Any) {
        callNumber(phoneNumber: "8005551234")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure why it works programmatically and not in storyboards but that's fine with me. I've got the text and button formatted and looking exactly how I need it, but the button doesn't work. There is a view on top of everything blocking me from being able to press the button. [Seen here...](http://imgur.com/A4eF9ZA). Any ideas?